# mysqljs-mysql transaction is too verbose. Simpler alternative?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, transactions

Here is a snippet of transaction with node-mysql from the [official github repo](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#transactions):

```
connection.beginTransaction(function(err) {
  if (err) { throw err; }
  connection.query('INSERT INTO posts SET title=?', title, function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) {
      return connection.rollback(function() {
        throw error;
      });
    }

    var log = 'Post ' + results.insertId + ' added';

    connection.query('INSERT INTO log SET data=?', log, function (error, results, fields) {
      if (error) {
        return connection.rollback(function() {
          throw error;
        });
      }
      connection.commit(function(err) {
        if (err) {
          return connection.rollback(function() {
            throw err;
          });
        }
        console.log('success!');
      });
    });
  });
});
```

I feel there are too much boilerplates over here. Isn't there a more succinct way of making a transaction, like this?:

```
/* invalid code */
connection.beginTransaction();
const q1 = connection.query("SELECT 1;");
const q2 = connection.query("SELECT 2;");
const q3 = connection.query("SELECT 3;");
if (q1 && q2 && q3) {
  connection.commit();
else {
  connection.rollback();
}
```

It would be synchronous in this case though.

Comment: You could use the promise-enabled API of the MySQL connector, which would make that code a lot cleaner. Then if you put it in an `async` function, you could use `await` to make it even cleaner still.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Is that official, or should I do like, `promisify`?

Comment: The `mysql2` npm module has it built in: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks, I will check, but it's kind of sad to change a library only because of this...

Comment: Well, as you say, you can use `util.promisify` (or the `promisify` module, which can do a whole API) instead.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it's a very late reply, but `mysql2` is working very nicely in my project. thank you.